# <body onload="MM_preloadImages... messing with other solution on this site

Tags: javascript, html, background-image, onload

I incorporated the scripting found in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14680041/change-div-background-jquery) into my website. It's not working in my site because I have a `<body onload="MM_preloadImages(...)">` (for preloading some rollover images) in the body marker. When I remove the onload and there's only a body tag, the Change div Background jquery script works just fine. The thing is, I need the pre-loading from the images too. Why is the script from the div background change conflicting with the body onload? How do I fix it?

My line of code looks like this now :

```
<body onload="MM_preloadImages('graphics/3d_print_down.png','graphics/over-down.png','graphics/contact-down.png','graphics/galerie-down.png')">
```

Comment: Note that Java and JavaScript are not the same language. JavaScript is what you're using here.

Comment: I don't see any reason for one to interact with the other.

Answer (score 0):

Does the jQuery code also add event handlers to the `body` element? If so it is likely that the `onload` attribute is overriding the handlers that the jQuery code is trying to add.

There are plenty of [jQuery plugins for pre-loading images](http://www.jquery4u.com/plugins/preload-image-plugins/) around; I would recommend removing the dodgy Dreamweaver-added code, adding a jQuery plugin that will do the same thing much better, and lastly switching to a better IDE ;)

Comment: Sadly to say that I'm a complete scripting rookie. I have no idea what to do.